# How can I identify web requests created when someone links to my site from Google+?

Tags: http-headers, user-agent, google-plus

To comply with new EU legislation regarding cookies, we've had to implement cookie 'warning' banners in several places on our site. We're now seeing problems when users try and link/embed content from our site on Facebook, Google+, bit.ly and so on - the embedded page thumbnail is showing the cookie notification banner instead of a preview of the actual page.

Most of these sites use a distinctive user agent string, so we can easily identify their incoming requests and disable the cookie banner - but Google+ seems to identify itself as

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0
```

which makes it very difficult to distinguish between Google+ automated requests and browsing traffic from 'real' users. Is there any way at all I can identify these requests? Custom HTTP headers I can look for or anything?

Answer (score 2):

G+ has got its user agent. It contains the text:  Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/).

Ref: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/#faq-snippet-useragent

Comment: please add more informaton to answer the question, not only the links, as they might be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

There are not any HTTP headers that you can depend on for detecting the +1 button page fetcher, but there is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=178) for it to specify a distinctive user agent. In the mean time, I would not depend on it.

You can, however, use other means to configure the snippet of content that appears on Google+. If you add structured markup such as schema.org or OpenGraph to your pages, the +1 button will pull the snippet from those tags. Google+ provides a [configuration tool and docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/) to help you design your markup.

If you add schema.org markup it might look something like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/trinket.jpg" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Doing a little further investigation, it appears that these request include an HTTP header X-Goog-Source, which - as far as we can tell - doesn't appear on any other incoming requests. This appears to be completely undocumented, but it seems to be our best option for now...

Comment: I did some poking around and it looks like this parameter is definitely not something you should depend on. It's not part of our specification and could change or vanish at any time. So proceed with caution and filter upon it at your own risk :)